# expect inside bash + wrong # args: should be "foreach varList list ?varList list ...? command"

Tags: bash, expect

I am using expect script inside bash script. When I use foreach inside expect script, it throws

> wrong # args: should be "foreach varList list ?varList list ...? command"

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter username: " username
read -s -p "Enter password: " password

#Expect script
/bin/expect -<<EOD 

set SERVERS {100 101 102}

foreach SERVER $SERVERS {
set timeout -1
spawn scp ${username}@plsa${SERVER}.corp.com:/log.2011-11-24 ${SERVER} 
expect "*password:"; send "$password\r"
expect eof }
EOD

echo "completed"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The heredoc (`<<ENDTOK`) is subject to shell expansion on the `$variables`.  That means for each of the `$variable`s you want expect to interpret, you'll need to escape the `$`.

---

The way to escape something is to prepend a slash to it (`$` -> `\$`).
It appears the username and password are supposed to come from the shell, the rest from within expect, so here's how that should go:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter username: " username
read -s -p "Enter password: " password

#Expect script
/bin/expect -<<EOD 

set SERVERS {100 101 102}

foreach SERVER \$SERVERS {
set timeout -1
spawn scp ${username}@plsa\${SERVER}.corp.com:/log.2011-11-24 \${SERVER} 
expect "*password:"; send "$password\r"
expect eof }
EOD

echo "completed"
```

Note the `\` in front of `$SERVERS` and `${SERVER}`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape dollar signs with a backslash since `$name` is expended to the value of variable `name`:

```
/bin/expect -<<EOD 

set SERVERS {100 101 102}

foreach SERVER \$SERVERS {
set timeout -1
spawn scp ${username}@plsa\${SERVER}.corp.com:/log.2011-11-24 \${SERVER} 
expect "*password:"; send "$password\r"
expect eof }
EOD
```

Comment: `$username` and `$password` come from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you quote your here-document delimiter, the embedded script is effectively quoted too:

```
/bin/expect -<<'EOD' 
... expect script as posted ...
EOD
```